# Angular5 + Node Express - all in TypeScript + Shared models folder

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, mean-stack

It's common that the MEAN stack apps (fully written in TypeScript) share the same typescript models.

My goal is to organise a nice project structure having the following directories:

```
client-src
server-src
shared

client-dist
server-dist
package.json
```

And I want to use AngularCLI as well.

Generally, I like how this https://github.com/DavideViolante/Angular-Full-Stack project is structured. Except for the absence of shared models folder.

What could be an approach to build such structure? Would it be possible to import models from the folder outside of the AngularCLI project folder without compilation issues?

Comment: Not really answering your questions but I'm also working on a MEAN Stack (Full TS) but I use TSOA. I generate the interfaces/services for the Client side with the Controllers and Models from the Server. If you're interested, here's my repo: https://github.com/nartc/tsoa-sandbox